# Can I make handmade invitation cards on a tight budget?

Tags: material-selection

I'm planning on making DIY cards for invitations to my sister's 8th birthday party. I want it to be special so I decided to do everything myself. But I'm really on a tight budget right now, and so I need advice on what materials I can use which will not exceed my allowance.

Comment: I'm closing this question off-topic because broad how-to guides and [idea generation questions](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-we-deal-with-idea-generation-questions) are not on-topic for our stack.

Comment: Seems a bit tight to close this one. Question was on materials for low budget hand -crafted- cards, not ideas on what to put on them. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @rebusB, it's still a shopping question, which is considered [off-topic on the whole of SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad).

Answer (score 1):

If you have plain white paper that is thick enough to make invitations cards, you can do the rest with free materials.

Cut and fold the paper into cards, then neatly write the invitation. 
Cut decorative forms like hearts, lollipops, bonbons or Hello Kitty heads and glue them onto the cards. You can cut these forms out of colorfull sheets of ads or catalogs or anything colorfull you have lying around.

Catalogs for clothes or furniture often have single items printed very big (like a carpet, windows drapes or a t-shirt). The only disadvantage is that the pages are often so thin you can see the backside through.

An alternative is wrapping paper. If it's the birthday of your little sister, you probably have a gift to wrap for her. Use some scraps of that paper to decorate the cards. Pieces of gift wrap ribbons add a special flair.

Depending on what you have lying around at home, you can also repurpose things like confetti, glitter, small beads or golden makeup powder do decorate the cards.

Take care not to add *too much* to the card. 1 - 3 decorations are enough to make the card look special.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I'm currently making them right now, still 27 out of 50 pieces and thank God mom is helping out. lol, it's gonna be a lot of work but I know it's going to be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ink pad and decorative rubber stamps to make your cards as well, they are available in most art or craft stores. To save on the budget you could cut patterns into potato halves and use an ink or paint soaked sponge as the ink pad. Either way they would let you decorate a number of matching cards quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

My hint is how I made my wedding invitations: I used pressed flowers.  As Elmy explained above, fold cardstock or construction paper into invitation cards and write the invitations carefully.  Pick the nicest blooms from some local flowers (with permission from the gardener, of course!) and immediately press for a few days by placing them carefully between layers of newspaper, and weighting the paper with books.  When they are dry, use school glue to decorate the cards.

To protect the flowers, you can either place them in the envelopes with a piece of waxed paper held over the flowers, or alternatively, put the flowers on the inside of the card rather than the outside.

Each invitation will be a one of a kind work of art!